# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

```
 Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1.    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Test  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference
```

I try to build Microsoft sample https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc

I have installed Netcore SDK 2.1.4

`dotnet --info` shows 2.0.5

Why it shows error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dev branch always targets the latest nightly builds (2.1.0 pre-preview ones). Use one of the tags, such as the `rel/2.0.0` branch which targets the ASP.NET Core 2.0.0. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/rel/2.0.0/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc.

.NET Core 2.1 is not out yet. An Preview 1 is expected later in Q1 and full release is expected in Q2.

Answer (score 3):

For those stumbling upon this question in a more general context, the issue is that .Net SDK 2.1.4 doesn't support .Net Core 2.1.

.Net Core 2.1 is supported by SDK 2.1.300 and above.

Download here https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-rc1

The confusion here comes from differences in the versioning between the CLI and .Net Core. The SDK version is actually the CLI version and that's not the same as the .Net Core version that's supported.

Thankfully there are plans to tidy this up and more info can be found in this GitHub discussion https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/29